# Remove punctuation from textfile error - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, filenames

I'm attempting to make a program that removes all punctuation from a textfile, however I keep running into an error where it only prints the title of the file rather than the contents within the file.

```
def removePunctuation(word):
    punctuation_list=['.', ',', '?', '!', ';', ':', '\\', '/', "'", '"']

    for character in word:
        for punctuation in punctuation_list:
            if character == punctuation:
                word = word.replace(punctuation, "")

    return word
print(removePunctuation('phrases.txt'))
```

Whenever I run the code, it just prints the name of the file; 'phrasestxt' without any punctuation. I want the program to print all the text that is present within the document, which is a few paragraphs long. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you must open your file and read it:

```
def removePunctuation(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fd:
        word = fd.read()
    punctuation_list=['.', ',', '?', '!', ';', ':', '\\', '/', "'", '"']

    for character in word:
        for punctuation in punctuation_list:
            if character == punctuation:
                word = word.replace(punctuation, "")

    return word
print(removePunctuation('phrases.txt'))
```

If you want, you can replace your double for loop by

```
word = "".join([i for i in word if i not in punctuation_list])
```